# What should be service api for aws_api_gateway_integration with firehose in terraform

Tags: aws-api-gateway, terraform, amazon-kinesis-firehose

As per terraform doc, uri for the aws_api_gateway_integration should be

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {

    ...
    ...
    uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:firehose:PutRecord/{service_api}"

}
```

I am not able to figure out what the service_api should be. Can you please help?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration.html

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question? I have the same problem and I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  type = "AWS"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:firehose:action/PutRecord"
```

Comment: beware copy+pasting the URI above - it contains zero-width whitespace characters - it prints like it should but it really is `arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:firehose:action/PutRec\u200c\u200bord` and that will lead to an `UnknownOperationException` on API Gateway - cost me hours.

Comment: @squidfunk It looks like the original answer was edited to remove the zero width whitespace. Can you verify for future users?

Comment: @CSBatchelor yes, I can confirm that the zero-width whitespace characters were removed from this answer, so copying it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

I found an example [here](https://github.com/udacity/kinesis_tf):

```
type                    = "AWS"
integration_http_method = "POST"
uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:kinesis:action/DescribeStream"
```

Example taken from [here](https://github.com/udacity/kinesis_tf/blob/master/api_describe_stream.tf):

Comment: Soren, I was able to get it working using "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:firehose:action/PutRecord". Hope it helps. Also i got the entire serverless stack working using api gateway and firehose. You can ask me if you have any other questions.