# I'AWS_PROXY' currently only supports Lambda function and Firehose stream invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to create an API Gateway that is connected to a kinesis stream:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.kinesis.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource_kinesis.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.post_kinesis.http_method
  type                 = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                  = "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1:kinesis:action/PutRecord"
  integration_http_method     = "POST"
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_resource.resource_kinesis
  ]
}

resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "kinesis-stream" {
  name        = "kinesis-stream"
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn   = aws_iam_role.integration_role.arn
    bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.arn

    processing_configuration {
      enabled = "true"

      processors {
        type = "Lambda"

        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "LambdaArn"
          parameter_value = "${aws_lambda_function.mylambda.arn}:$LATEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
Error creating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action
│ 
│   with module.api.aws_api_gateway_integration.kinesis_integration,
│   on ../../modules/myapi.tf line 62, in resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration":
│   62: resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration" {
```

Am I using the wrong syntax? Is it not supposed to be a string? I read in another SO answer that the format of the uri is supposed to be like this:

```
arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:{path|action}/{service_api}
```

but it doesn't seem to work for me. I already tried both sols here but they give me the same error:
[What should be service api for aws_api_gateway_integration with firehose in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859122/what-should-be-service-api-for-aws-api-gateway-integration-with-firehose-in-terr)

Comment: well the qs was for AWS Proxy specifically and I still haven't been able to resolve the error so I guess I will leave the qs open @Marcin

Comment: I already wrote, there is no AWS_PROXY for Firehose.

Comment: Hm still confused why its written in the error tho. Also i saw some tutorial with AWX Proxy + Firehose..can't find it again rn but that tutorial is why i started doing this in the first place @Marcin

Comment: It's a placeholder probably. Aws maybe working on this internally and the error msg already contains this.

Answer (score 0):

The links that you are trying to follow are for `AWS` integration, not `AWS_PROXY`. `AWS_PROXY` is only for lambda functions. I know that somewhere it says you can also use Firehose with it (I think some error messages), but its not really documented and advertised. It is either some internal AWS functionality, or something that hasn't been implemented yet.