# Terraform : Error creating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm integrating aws firehouse with API gateway post call.

I know here the issue is with the uri.

My Terraform code looks like this.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "request_method_integration_post" {

rest_api_id = local.rest_api_id
resource_id = local.resource_id
http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.request_method_post.http_method
type        = "AWS"
integration_http_method = "POST"
uri = 
"arn:aws:apigateway:${local.region_name}:firehose:arn:aws:firehose:${local.region_name}:${var.accountId}:deliverystream/${var.firehose_name}/PutRecord"
}
```

According to the documentation uri should have the below pattern

```
arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:{path|action}/{service_api}
```

reference :
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration

**But I cannot figure out the correct uri here.**

*If anyone knows please help.*

I tried to change the uri with different formats.

I also tried with the following.
`uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:firehose:action/PutRecord"`

Non works.

Comment: Please add the rest of the code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

uri should be as follow.

```
"arn:aws:apigateway:${local.region_name}:firehose:action/PutRecordBatch"
```

Also credentials was missing in my `aws_api_gateway_integration` resource.
Should be look like,

```
credentials             = aws_iam_role.name.arn
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859122/what-should-be-service-api-for-aws-api-gateway-integration-with-firehose-in-terr)

You should have the following values and format:

```
type = "AWS"
integration_http_method = "POST"
uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:firehose:action/PutRecord"
```

Comment: I also tried with the following.
uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:firehose:action/PutRecord"
Still error remains same.